# 'www' CNAME is not resolving properly, root A records working fine though (for Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, heroku, cname, whm

I'm having trouble using WHM/Cpanel to set up CNAME records for my heroku app.

I've set up the records as follows - [see link to image](http://i56.tinypic.com/2qk17at.png).

dapcards.com is resolving to the heroku app with no problems.

However, www.dapcards.com fails:

```
> host dapcards.com
dapcards.com has address 75.101.145.87
dapcards.com has address 75.101.163.44
dapcards.com has address 174.129.212.2
dapcards.com mail is handled by 0 dapcards.com.
> host www.dapcards.com
Host www.dapcards.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Host www.dapcards.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

When I use the dnsstuff.com tool, it seems to get to proxy.heroku.com fine, but produces an error:

```
[BOGUS ANSWER: This server is not authoritative for proxy.heroku.com.: 
it refers back to the root servers]
```

http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools/legacy/?formaction=DNSLOOKUP&ToolFormName=customlookup&name=www.dapcards.com&r=235660&detail=0&type=CNAME

I'm obviously missing something here.  Has anyone got any ideas?  Would really appreciate some advice!

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you didn't wait long enough for DNS to propagate? Looks fine here:

```
$ host www.dapcards.com
www.dapcards.com is an alias for proxy.heroku.com.
proxy.heroku.com has address 50.16.233.102
proxy.heroku.com has address 174.129.212.2
proxy.heroku.com has address 75.101.145.87
$ host dapcards.com
dapcards.com has address 75.101.145.87
dapcards.com has address 75.101.163.44
dapcards.com has address 174.129.212.2
dapcards.com mail is handled by 0 dapcards.com.
```

Comment: Hm - thanks for replying so quick.  Is the site loading in your browser?  It's actually www.dapshare.com that I'm more worried about, but I panicked and setup zoneedit.com instead. Maybe I just need to be more patient!  www.dapcards.com still not resolving for me, but I'll give it 24 hours and see if anything changes...

Comment: @Rob, "Launching Mid-2011!" on both www.dapshare.com and dapshare.com.

Comment: Thanks sarnold - resolving fine for me now.

Answer (score 1):

I just accessed your website unter both www.dapcards.com and dapcards.com in my browser and the site renders fine :)

Comment: Hm.  Awesome.  Thanks for your troubles!  Maybe DNS refreshes are sent via snail-mail to Australia :)